# PHP will not compile with MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb, compiler-errors, configure, php-5.5

So i'm trying to build PHP 5.5.9 with MongoDB driver 1.5 (i know, we're back in 2014!) but I'm running into an error when I run ./configure :

```
checking whether to enable MongoDB support... yes
./configure: line 59477: syntax error near unexpected token src/libmongoc/src/common/,'
./configure: line 59477:   PHP_MONGODB_ADD_SOURCES(src/libmongoc/src/common/, $PHP_MONGODB_COMMON_SOURCES, $PHP_MONGODB_BUNDLED_CFLAGS)'
```

It's as if there is supposed to be a function PHP_MONGODB_ADD_SOURCES that does not exist in the configure script... How do I fix this?

I'm running this on an AWS Linux AMI (not verson 2) so that I can create a php runtime for use with Lambda functions, and I need the mongodb driver compiled into it.

Here is all the commands i've used when i've ssh'd into a fresh instance:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y \
   pcre.x86_64 \
   libxml2-devel \
   libmcrypt-devel.x86_64 \
   bzip2-devel.x86_64 \
   libcurl-devel.x86_64 \
   openssl-devel.x86_64 \
   libpng-devel.x86_64 \
   libicu-devel.x86_64 \
   libedit-devel.x86_64 \
   readline-devel.x86_64 \
   git.x86_64 \
   php-devel.x86_64

sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

curl -o php-5.5.9.tar.gz https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.5.9.tar.gz
tar xvzf php-5.5.9.tar.gz
cd php-5.5.9

#have to install php to get phpize!
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --sysconfdir=/etc \
            --with-config-file-path=/etc 
sudo make
sudo make install


git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
cd mongo-php-driver
git checkout -b v1.5
git submodule update --init
phpize
sudo ./configure
sudo make all
sudo make install

cd ../../
rm configure
./buildconf --force
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --sysconfdir=/etc \
            --with-config-file-path=/etc \
            --with-mcrypt \
            --enable-bcmath \
            --with-bz2 \
            --enable-calendar \
            --enable-ctype \
            --with-curl \
            --enable-dba=shared \
            --enable-dom \
            --enable-exif \
            --enable-fileinfo \
            --enable-ftp \
            --with-gd \
            --with-gettext\
            --enable-hash \
            --with-iconv \
            --enable-intl \
            --enable-json \
            --enable-libxml \
            --enable-mbstring \
            --with-mhash \
            --enable-mysqlnd \
            --with-openssl \
            --with-pcre-regex \
            --enable-pdo \
            --with-pdo-mysql \
            --enable-phar \
            --enable-posix \
            --with-readline \
            --enable-session \
            --enable-shmop \
            --enable-simplexml \
            --enable-soap \
            --enable-sockets \
            --enable-sysvmsg \
            --enable-tokenizer \
            --enable-wddx \
            --enable-xml \
            --enable-xmlreader \
            --enable-xmlwriter \
            --enable-opcache \
            --enable-zip \
            --with-zlib \
            --enable-sysvsem \
            --enable-sysvshm \
            --enable-mongodb
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As a quick-and-dirty work-around you could try replacing the missing-dependancy-function "PHP_MONGODB_ADD_SOURCES" with "PHP_ADD_SOURCES" in the file mongo-php-driver/config.m4

Here's the rationale:

- PHP_MONGODB_ADD_SOURCES is defined in the file: scripts/autotools/m4/php_mongodb.m4
- All that function does is some input validation and then calls either PHP_ADD_SOURCES or PHP_ADD_SOURCES_X on the same inputs. These functions appear to have sources from other dependencies that may exist.
- The "_X" version appears to be less common. So simply find-replace PHP_MONGODB_ADD_SOURCES with PHP_ADD_SOURCES in config.m4

Comment: Although this wasn't the solution i used, it did point me into the right direction. What I ended up doing was copying the contents of  scripts/autotools/m4/php_mongodb.m4 into the top of config.m4 and it did compile. Now i'll test it and see if it actually worked. Thanksfor the response!